# Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS terminal sudo don’t recognize my password

Tags: sudo, password

I installed Ubuntu using Windows10 subfolder. I know the password I set at installation is the correct one, but when using Sudo command at the terminal, even though, I’m entering the correct password it’s still asking me to enter. Sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts.I know that I’m entering the correct password. Help please, what can I do to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: nothing like caps inadvertently on?

Comment: did you check if the correct keyboard language is set up? Maybe try typing the password as clear text in the terminal (without hiting enter) and see if there is something odd.

Comment: Thanks for trying to helpWhen is asking me for the password, while I’m entering it, I noticed that the cursor is not moving.